# How to determine a set of nodes based on the incoming relationship of another set of nodes and some special conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a Cypher query that gets a set of nodes 'n' of type 't', say (it works it's way through a number of different node types in the graph to reach this point).

If we assume the following:

- The rest of type t nodes are the set 'm', so no intersect between m and n.
- Type t nodes have multiple types of relationships between them.

I have a specific relationship 'r' that I'm interested in.  In this specific case I know the following to be true:

- Type t nodes can have 0 or more of these r relationships, incoming/outgoing.
- The nodes within set n have no outgoing r relationships to set m
- The nodes within set m may have outgoing r relationships to set m or n.

I have set n, I'm trying to determine the nodes from set m that meet the following conditions:

- Have 0 r relationships
  OR
- Only have r relationships to set n, but not to any node in set m.

Some example data:

Type t nodes:

n1, n2, n3
m1, m2, m3

Type r relationships

m1  (no r relationships)
m2->n1, m2->n2
m3->n3, m3->m2

The results should return m1 and m2, but not m3.

I'm quite new to Cypher, so feel free to point to relevant documentation as required.  Also, if you can explain the process you go through to determine the answer, I'd appreciate that as I suspect I'm just not quite understanding something simple here.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is more model than data, you may know how to tell m:s and n:s apart but I cant write a query on the identifiers alone, there must be some actual data or structure to discriminate. For isntance, assume all nodes in the graph are type `t`, let sets `n`, `m` be distinguished by labels `:N`, `:M`, let the identifiers you use be values for property `uid` (to make the query results map with your question), and let type r relationship be `[:R]`, then create your graph with

```
CREATE 
  (n1:N{uid:"n1"}), (n2:N{uid:"n2"}), (n3:N{uid:"n3"})
  ,(m1:M{uid:"m1"}), (m2:M{uid:"m2"}), (m3:M{uid:"m3"})
  , m2-[:R]->n1, m2-[:R]->n2
  , m3-[:R]->n3, m3-[:R]->m2
```

The query could then look something like

```
MATCH (n:N)                   // bind each node in the set n
WITH collect(n) AS nn         // collect and treat them as a set nn
MATCH (m:M)                   // grab each node in the set m
OPTIONAL MATCH m-[:R]->(x)    // optionally expand from m to unknown by r
WITH nn, m, collect(x) AS xx  // collect unknown per m as xx where
WHERE ALL (x IN xx            // all unknown nodes are in the nn set
           WHERE x IN nn)     // (if m has no -[:R]-> then the set xx is empty
                              //   and the condition is true–i.e. 
                              //   either m has no outgoing r or
                              //   the other node is in nn)
RETURN m
```

Result

```
m
(3:M {uid:"m1"})
(4:M {uid:"m2"})
```

You can try the query [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=dfr4it).

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive reply (also, the linked 'live' query is great).  I can see I used some wrong terminology in my question.  Where I say type, it's should be a label?  Where you use :N and :M, I would be using :T for both.  And if I understand you correctly, this lack of distinction is a problem.  I was hoping to do set style manipulation to get m (it's all :T without n).  I assume if I had that, I could use the MATCH (m:M)...etc portion of your query to get the result required.